# Connecting MySQL Database Java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I want to connect my java application to an MySql server.

In netbeans i use these strings :

```
String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Oratorio";

    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"); //... Carica il Driver 
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
```

But if I build this program it doesnt connect to the database.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: This code makes my brain hurt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to connect to a MySQL database using the Derby connector, you are not going to succeed.

You need to use a connector that can actually connect to your database.

Comment: can you give me an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the MySQL Connector JAR, then you can connect like this, it is only a snippet!
URL, USERNAME and PASSWORD are Stringconstants with the Username/Password for accessing the DB and the URL is like "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<'DB_NAME'>"

[...]

```
 try { 
Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); DriverManager.registerDriver(driver); 
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had a school project and I had to use mysql(it was a quiz game). I made an SQLHandler class, wich is really universal, you can use it in every projects, wich include the jdbc mysql connector, wich can be downloaded from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). I downloaded the platform independent version, wich is a jar file. Feel free to use the code below:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SQLHandler {
private String host;
private String port;
private String db;
private String user;
private String pw;
public SQLHandler(String host,String port, String db, String user,String pw){
    this.host=host;
    this.port=port;
    this.db=db;
    this.user=user;
    this.pw=pw;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public String getHost(){
    return host;
}
public String getPort(){
    return port;
}
public String getDb(){
    return db;
}
public String getPw(){
    return pw;
}
public String getUser(){
    return user;
}
public String URLConfig(String host, String port, String dbaseName){
    String url="jdbc:mysql://"+host+":"+port+"/"+dbaseName;
    return url;
}
public void inputQuery(String command) throws SQLException{
    String url=URLConfig(getHost(),getPort(),getDb());
    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,getUser(),getPw());
    PreparedStatement query=conn.prepareStatement(command);
    query.executeUpdate(command);
}
public String outputQuery(String command,int cnum)throws SQLException{ //cnum defines the number of columns in your table
    String url=URLConfig(getHost(),getPort(),getDb());
    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,getUser(),getPw());

    PreparedStatement query=conn.prepareStatement(parancs);
    ResultSet result=query.executeQuery(parancs);
    String res="";
    while(result.next()){
        for(int i=1; i<=cnum; i++){
            res=res+result.getString(i)+" ";
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

}

I hope it will help you!